# dplyr - element-wise summarise in nested lists

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,2,2))
df$X2 <- list(list(1, 2), list(0, 1), list(1,0))

df
  X1    X2
1  1  1, 2
2  2  0, 1
3  2  1, 0
```

---

Now, I would like to add a new column that is the element-wise mean of all the lists in `X2` that share the same `X1` value, e.g.:

```
  X1  mean
1  1  1, 2
2  2  0.5, 0.5
```

---

I tried with the following instructions:

```
df %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarise(mean = mean(X2))
```

But all I get is

```
     X1  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  1.00    NA
2  2.00    NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X2) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

---

**How can I build this new column?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use

```
df <- df %>% group_by(X1) %>% 
  summarise(mean = list(map(reduce(X2, `map2`, `+`), `/`, n())))
df$mean
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 2
#
#
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 0.5
#
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 0.5
```

**Explanation**: first, after grouping, with

```
reduce(X2, `map2`, `+`)
```

we add all the lists element-wise. Then as to get the mean we use another `map` with `/`. Lastly, `list` returns a list.

**Update**: you may also use

```
df %>% group_by(X1) %>%
  summarise(mean = list(pmap(X2, ~ sum(...) / n())))
```

or

```
df %>% group_by(X1) %>%
  summarise(mean = list(pmap(X2, ~ mean(c(...)))))
```

Unfortunately `list(pmap(X2, mean))` doesn't work as

```
mean(1, 2)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: @Lovy, I added a couple of shorter and more readable alternatives.